# Linear Algebra Basis For Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let V = $(Z_7)^4$, and let W = $(a, 2a,a+2b,b+c)|a,b,c ∈ Z_7 .$
>
> Find a basis for W.

Here's my solution.

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

then elimination;
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

In this case can we say that the basis is {$a, a +2b, b+c$} ?

Comment: Your matrix is transposed.

Comment: @DougM Do you mean it should be this? \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} ?

Comment: indeed, and the columns can be your basis.

Comment: @DougM so {$a, a +2b, b+c$} is not a basis?

Comment: Your basis needs to be a subset of $V$ Which is a 4 dimensional vector space.  Therefore you need 4 dimensional vectors in your basis.  Furthermore consider the matrix multiplication of $A\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$  What matrix gives you $W$?

Comment: @Antt It is not, because a,b,c are not elements in $(Z_7)^4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is commented, $a,b,c$ are *scalars* and not elements of $V$. We need specific occurances for these scalars to obtain a basis for $W$.

No elimination is needed here, the rows of your first matrix will already give a basis.

So, our subspace will have elements $(a,\,2a,\,a+2b,\,b+c)$ for all possible scalars $a,b,c$.

An easy procedure to obtain a basis for such a case is to plug in $a=1,\ b=c=0$ then $b=1,\ c=a=0$ and then $c=1,\ a=b=0$, which now indeed gives
$$\big[ (1,2,1,0),\ (0,0,2,1),\ (0,0,0,1)  \big]\,.$$